# Does Anaconda check bashrc file for CC??? path?

Tags: bash, cmake, anaconda, python-venv

I think I have seen others who have had this same issue, but perhaps it is due to  where the Anaconda image is being run on the system ( i.e where the venv is that pip has installed)

Just a note that my processor- arch is x86, and with some older style bus and memory layout.

Comment: ~/.bashrc is only read by bash when starting an interactive shell. Environment variables it sets will be passed to child processes. Anaconda does not read ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

What's more likely is that `CC` environment variable is affecting pip/make/autotools.

You can view your environment variable's value by running:

```
env |grep ^CC=
```

The `~/.bashrc` file itself isn't read unless an interactive shell is launched, so for those shell scripts and/or Make calls that pip uses to compile Python modules, it's not likely to be sourced, but any process spawned from a shell where the `CC` environment variable is set will inherit that environment variable, regardless of whether it reads `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: It appears more recent versions of conda have bash cpletion, not sure at what point that started. If so, and my version is one that does, perhaps  it is an option for making sure env variables are read from my interpretative shell ( eg current process) and not any parent process settings????   Sorry but my version is 3.4, so my guess is In a bit outdated